# Emacs flycheck package installation

Tags: emacs, flycheck

I try to use the flycheck package which I installed through the package-list.

Following advices from [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2015-04-02-emacs-flycheck-eslint-jsx.html) I added this line to my .emacs:

```
(require 'flycheck)
```

Now I get the following error when starting emacs:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `~/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no file or folder of this type, flycheck
```

Is this line no longer required? 
Should I add other lines instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok following [flycheck documentation](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/installation.html) I installed the package "use-package" and added the following to my config file:

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
```

Now it works.